# Would visual studio 2010 work in windows server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have alot of files currently in the Visual studio 2010. I would like to know if I use Windows server 2008 ? Would the files(classes, sln)still work?.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're asking if you install Visual Studio 2010 on a Server 2008 box, will that work and will you still be able to open your files/solutions?

The answer is Yes for VS2010 Premium or Ultimate on Server 2008 SP2. Also, the 64-bit version (only) of VS2010 will install on Server 2008 R2. For complete OS requirements, see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg265786%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe they would. We use Visual Studio 2010 on a number of different computers and operating systems, same files, without issue.